# Textarea value not cleared

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem is that I have a HTML `<textarea>` element and a button which should clear the textarea. But for some reason this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function clear() {
  document.getElementById('output').value = '';
}
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="false" rows="8" cols="80" id="output">Lorem Impsum</textarea>
<button onclick="clear()">Clear Output</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`clear` is a reserve word in JavaScript. Please change the name of your function.

```js
function clearText() {
   document.getElementById('output').value = '';
}
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="false" rows="8" cols="80" id="output">Lorem Impsum</textarea>
<button onclick="clearText()">Clear Output</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're clearing the HTML property, but the function name is reserved. To clear the element you can do:

```
function clearOutput() {
  const el = document.getElementById('output');
  
  el.value = '';
}
```

As a side note, you really shouldn't use the `onclick` attribute, it's better to bind events using `addEventListener`.

Comment: Clearing `innerHTML` simply isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Textarea uses .innerHTML not .value and also clear() name wont work because it is already defined in vanilla javascript so clear1(). The below code should work -

```js
function clear1() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="false" rows="8" cols="80" id="output">Lorem Impsum</textarea>
<button onclick="clear1()">Clear Output</button>
```